# Why does Passenger 3.0 with nginx crash on startup(?) then 403s?

Tags: nginx, passenger

On Ubuntu with REE 1.8.7, with nginx 0.8.53 manually compiled with the
Passenger 3 module doc installed as per the docs, I get an error in
the nginx error log when nginx starts:

Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered
the following error during startup: Unable to start the Phusion
Passenger logging agent: an error occurred while sending startup
arguments: Broken pipe (32) (-1: Unknown error 18446744073709551615)

I assume this means nginx never starts properly.  When I try and view
my site after this, I get a 403.

2010/10/22 00:56:47 [error] 13874#0: *1813942 directory index of "/var/
rails/myapp/current/public/" is forbidden, client: 125.197.115.16,
server: new.myapp.fm, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "new.myapp.fm"

I expect the first is probably causing the second.  I haven't had any
luck googling this.  Can anyone provide insight or help me
troubleshoot?

Comment: Are those the only errors? Are there no other errors in the logs?

Comment: Any answer to this? I am getting this as well. 

Restarting nginx: [alert]: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1 (-1: Unknown error 18446744073709551615)
nginx.

Comment: No answers yet.  @Hongli, yes, these are the only errors.

Comment: And Standalone, does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that PassengerLoggingAgent wasn't installed when I did  'gem install passenger'.  I installed it as per this discussion (by grabbing it from the standalone zip) and everything is fine now: http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/323dc1c7b0e5ee11

Answer (score 1):

I got this after upgrading to Passenger 3.0.1 as I had not changed the version of Passenger specified by passenger_root in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf. You might need to change the line that looks like this to specify the correct version:

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.1;
```

You get told to do this when you install nginx. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too, and it was because passenger couldn't find ruby:

tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
2011/12/20 00:54:45 [alert] 30300#0: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger helper agent: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1 (-1: Unknown error)
*** Passenger ERROR (ext/common/ApplicationPool/../SpawnManager.h:220):
Could not start the spawn server: ruby: No such file or directory (2)

Even though ruby was properly listed within the system PATH, it didn't seem to work right until I added:

```
passenger_ruby = /usr/local/bin/ruby;
```

(the location of my ruby executable) into the http section of my nginx config.